# solving a strange Diophantine equation ${\sqrt{n}}^\sqrt{n} -11 =m!^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial

> Does anyone know how to solve Diophantine equation: $${\sqrt{n}}^\sqrt{n}-11 =m!^2.$$

I tried to substitute $\sqrt{n}=k$ then equation becomes $$k^k-11=m!^2\\\implies k^k=m!^2+11=(m!-1)(m!+1)+12$$ which means suppose $m\geq2$ then $\gcd{(m!-1,m!+1)}=1$. Does this give any hint? I could think upto here only. Please help.

Comment: It should help that after $m=9$, the number $m!^2 + 11$ will end in "11".

Comment: $n$ must be a perfect square. Otherwise $\sqrt n^{\sqrt n}$ would be trascendental. Together with Aston's comment and the fact that no square can end with $11$, this implies that $n$ must be an odd perfect square.

Comment: $k^k\equiv (m!+1)(m!-1)\pmod 4$. Then $k^k\equiv-1\pmod 4$. So, $k\equiv -1\pmod 4$.

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: @ajotatxe:  We want $k^k$ to end with $11$, not the square.

Comment: $k$ must be odd because all the factorials aside from $1$ are even.  I would try $k=1,3,5,7$ and report failure.  $3^3-11$ gives a square, but $4$ is not a factorial.  Then squares are so rare it won't happen.

Comment: If $m \geq 11$, then $11 \mid m!$ and so $11 \| m!^2+11$. It follows that $11 \| k^k$, a contradiction.

Comment: what does || symbol mean?

Comment: Exactly divides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$k^k-11 = (m!)^2.$$
If $k>=11$ then $$121\not|\, LHS,\quad 121\,|\, RHS,\quad LHS\not= RHS.$$
In the other hand, $k$ is odd and $k^k > 11$, so
$$k\in\{3,5,7,9\}.$$
Note than:
$$\sqrt{3^3-11} = 4 \not= m!,$$
$$\sqrt{5^5-11} = \sqrt{3114}\in(55,56),\quad \sqrt{5^5-11}\not\in\mathbb N,$$
$$\sqrt{7^7-11} = \sqrt{823532}\in(907,908),\quad \sqrt{7^7-11}\not\in\mathbb N,$$
$$\sqrt{9^9-11} = \sqrt{387420478}= \sqrt{11683^2-1}\in(11682,11683),\quad \sqrt{9^9-11}\not\in\mathbb N.$$

So the issue diophantine equation has not solutions.